# Table view section issue while loading table view data in iOS

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm trying to load data in table view from an API response, from API response I get the array and pass it to the table view delegates and data sources. I want to show each element of array under a single section. I'm passing an array of section but when i load data it shows multiple elements under single section. This is how it looks,
[image]

This my code to show data,

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return headerArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 35
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let bgView = UIView()
    bgView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3221348226, green: 0.6953448653, blue: 0.9635410905, alpha: 1)
    bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    let titleLbl = UILabel()
    titleLbl.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 150, height: 20)
    titleLbl.text = headerArray[section]
    titleLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .semibold)
    titleLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    bgView.addSubview(titleLbl)

    return bgView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if vcType == "SellerInProcess"
    {
        return propertyObject?.owners?.count ?? 0
    }
    else
    {
        return ownersList?.count ?? 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let owners = ownerArray[indexPath.row]
    if owners.userType != nil && owners.userType == Identity.OWNER  {
            let cell :  OwnerListTableViewCell! =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OwnerListTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? OwnerListTableViewCell

            let ownerData = ownersList![indexPath.row]
            cell.ownerData = ownerData as? OwnerModel

            return cell
      }  
}
```

For section array i have made like this,

```
 var i = 1
                self?.headerArray.removeAll()
                for _ in self?.ownersList ?? []
                {
                    let index = i + 0
                    i += 1
                    self?.print(i,index)
                    let sectionString = "Owner \(index)"
                    self?.headerArray.append(sectionString)
                }
```

How i can show each element under a single section?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one cell inside each section, you need to return either 1 or 0 (for empty section) inside the `numberOfRowsInSection` method. You need to also modify the `cellForRow` section and use `indexPath.section` as array index to get the element for this section.

Also I would not prepare `headerArray`, since you can generate the string inside the `viewForHeaderInSection` because you will get the `section` variable and can do something like this: `let headerTitle = "Owner \(section + 1)"` +1 because indices are counted from zero.

Answer (score 0):

Organize your data appropriately.

For example create a model like

```
struct Section {
    let headerName : String
    let owner : WhateverItsTypeIs
}
```

and map your data to an array of this model

```
var sections = [Section]()
```

Then return `section.count` in `numberOfSections` and `1` (or `0` then make `owner` optional) in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Don't use multiple arrays as data source anyway.

Comment: actually i get only owners from api response, i want to add each element from owners array under a single section. @vadian

Comment: In your code you are using `headerArray`, `propertyObject` and `ownersList`. As I said you have to *organize you data appropriately*

Comment: let me clear it to you, i get data from api response and i have a model name OwnerModel, i store owners data in ownersList. Now at this point i just know i have ownerlist, i want to place a single section above each element in ownersList. Mean 
headerArray[0]  and . ownersList[0]. Got my point?. @vadian

Comment: Merge both arrays to struct items and use that as data source array. Or if the header name information is in OwnerList then use simply an array of OwnerList as data source.

Comment: Sorry this is very basic stuff and it’s fully explained in the answer(s). Please learn how the data source of a table view works.

Comment: I have make a model as you have mention in your answer and pass it to my numberofSection like this ownersDatas.count and numberForRows like this ownersDatas.count

Comment: No, please read my answer carefully. Return 1 for numberOfRows as you want to display **one** row per section

Comment: i'm not getting the point return 1 for numberOfRown where this 1 comes from?

Comment: The table view has sections and rows. The user data represents the rows. If you want to display **1** row per section you have to return **1**.